# Compare two files and move the common record to another file

Tags: unix, join, awk

There are two text files.

```
File1:
xchg_rat_to_cncy_cd=PLN
xchg_rat_to_cncy_cd=PLZ
xchg_rat_to_cncy_cd=PTE

File2:
epoc_id=1455718545/xchg_rat_to_cncy_cd=PLN
epoc_id=1455718545/xchg_rat_to_cncy_cd=PLZ
epoc_id=1455718545/xchg_rat_to_cncy_cd=PTE
```

*The number of fields is not limited to 1 in file1 or 2 in file2. but the 2nd file will always have the extra column as the first field.

This is what I tried till now with file1 have one column and file2 having 2 columns.

```
awk -F'/' 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} ($1 in a) {print a[$1],$1}' FILE1 FILE2
```

But this is only limited to file1 having 1 column and file2 having 2 columns.
I want to make it scalable so that it can handle files with n columns.

Kindly suggest a solution

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: If you `want to make it scalable so that it can handle files with n columns.` then edit your question so that the example you provide us has more than 2 columns otherwise we're guessing about what you might mean by that and what your requirements might be. Make the example concise but realistic and such that whatever solution you get for it you will be able to expand to use on your real data (so for example if you need to handle 1,000 fields, post an example with 5 or less fields, not 1,000). And add the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is somewhat unclear, but try this:

```
grep -f FILE1 FILE2
```

or

```
grep -o -f FILE1 FILE2
xchg_rat_to_cncy_cd=PLN
xchg_rat_to_cncy_cd=PLZ
xchg_rat_to_cncy_cd=PTE
```